# How to backup and restore Consumable In-App Purchase tracked in NSUserDefaults to/from iCloud or Dropbox?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview that lets users add 2 rows of item for free (int max in NSUserDefaults).  I have a pricing structure for in-app purchase as following:

```
+$1 for 1 more item 
+$4 for 5 more items 
+$7 for 10 more items...
```

These are Consumable In-App Purchases. Each productidentifier can be purchased multiple times. Every time a purchase is made, I increase the max number accordingly. I do keep track of how many times each productidentifier has been bought in the NSUserDefaults. I need a way to back the data up. The storekit framework doesn't provide a restoreCompletedTransactions method for Consumable In-App Purchase. I need a way for the users to restore all the Consumable Purchases after the users reinstall the app, change the device, restore the device and whatnot?

How do I backup and restore the purchases in say iCloud or Dropbox?

Thank you

Comment: I came across the suggested question above but the answers suggest using a server to restore the purchases which I clearly indicate that I don't want to do that in my case.

Comment: Keep in mind that there can be a difference between what needs to be done and what you want to do. :)

Comment: One solution would be to use `MKStoreKit` which stores consumable purchases in the iOS keychain.  The keychain is backed up via iTunes, but this wouldn't help if it's on a different device.  You'd still have to resort to a server-side solution in that scenario.

Comment: Could you clearly define your purchasable items?  Are they "the ability to add <n> items to the table" or is there some other more complete definition?

Comment: Yes, its the ability to add <n> rows to the tableview.

Comment: Looks like I may have to use a server after all. Can I backup and restore User Defaults and Core Data To say iCloud or Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

If as discussed in the comments, your purchase is the ability to add  items, I would recommend changing your purchase definitions.  Instead, have a series of purchases of the form

- P1: allow first 10 items or first 10 after a free set (or 10 items total)
- P2: allow next 10 items (or twenty items total)
- P3: allow a further 10 items (or 30 items total)
- ...
- Pn: allow the last set of ten items you think is reasonable.

Then modify your application so that the ability to purchase P(m) is only present if P(m-1) has been purchased.  In this way, you go from a consumable representation to a non-consumable which has a couple of advantages

- Apple manages restores
- It is much much easier to get right (not losing things, definition across devices, ...)
- I actually think it better represents what you are trying to do

The only reason I would see to use consumables is if you wanted users to "use up" these abilities over time.

Comment: I don't think I can set it up that way.

I have a tableview that let users add 2 rows of item for free(int max in NSUserDefaults). Then I have a pricing structure as following:

+$1 for 1 more item
+$4 for 5 more items
+$7 for 10 more items...

Each productidentifier can be purchased multiple times. Every time a purchase is made, I increase the max number accordingly. I do keep track of how many times each productidentifier has been bought in the NSUserDefaults. I need a way to back those data up. I'm looking at iCloud or Dropbox backup.

Comment: You can if you want.  Just have one product "stream" for each multiplier.  Only show the next one in a stream when the previous is purchased.  The number available is based on the sum of the furthest in each stream.